# MongoDB, Using mongorestore on an .agz file

Tags: restore, gzip, mongodb

I am using MongoDB 3.6 and am having trouble understanding how to use mongorestore on an .agz file. If I specify the below, then I get an error saying `Failed: error connecting to db server: no reachable servers`

```
mongorestore --gzip --archive=<filename>.agz --db test
```

And when I use the below command, specifying the actual mongod instance, I don't get any errors and actually see the status `preparing collections to restore from`, but I don't see anything in the actual mongod instance

```
mongorestore --gzip --archive=<filename>.agz --db test -u <username> -p <password> --authenticationDatabase 'admin' --port 27000 --host <hostname>
```

What am I supposed to be doing instead?

Answer (score 2):

I figured out my issue.....The second command that I listed above (with the username and password) works, I just had the wrong `db` name.

I thought it could be any `db` name you want and it would create it in the new instance you are restoring to, but I realized that the `db` has to be match the name from the instance you use the `mongodump` command on

Comment: I just used `mongorestore.exe --gzip --archive=..\..\old_data.agz` and it made the old_data collection in my local MongoDB.

Comment: The above worked for me well, Thanks !!